# strip all <a> tags except those that start with http

Tags: html, regex

I would like to remove all  tags that start with href="http: and leave the text being linked in place for each of them.

There are other  tags in my html file that I don't want changed at all. Again, I only want the  tags that start with http stripped with the text being linked staying in place.

Essentially I want all external links stripped from the html document and the internal links to remain intact.

Any help with the right Find What: and Replace with: information would be appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1848654

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to do this with Find/Replace? Are you editing the HTML file in a text editor?

Answer (score 2):

You could remove all tags that don't contain the current host:

```js
const links = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('a'))
links.forEach(elm => {
  !elm.href.includes(window.location.host) && elm.parentNode.removeChild(elm);
})
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com">google</a>
<a href="/about">about</a>
```

no need for JQuery

Answer (score 0):

A  solution could be something like

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {

//stores all a tags in an array.
var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var re = new RegExp("^http://");
var length = aTags.length;

for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if( aTags[i].href.test(re) ) {
         aTags[i].href = "https://" //reset to something else if true?

         //OR

         aTags[i].href.replace("http://", "https://"); //replace with https
    }
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following JavaScript should replace all links with the text, they contain:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var regEx = /^https?:\/\//;

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
{
    var elem = links[i];
    if (elem.href.test(regEx))
    {
        var node = document.createTextNode(elem.textContent);
        elem.parentElement.replaceChild(node, elem);
    }
}
```

It loops through all links and if they start with '`http://`' or '`https://`', a textnode is created with the text, and that textnode replaces the link.